# Swift array created by class from another language

Tags: php, ios, swift

I have got a HTTP request in my Swift code that sends a POST request to my PHP code.Here is my php code

```
class Comment
{
    public $CommenterName;
    public $CommentDate;
    public $CommentLikes;
    function __construct($CommenterName,$CommentDate,$CommentLikes)
    {
        $this->CommenterName = $CommenterName;
        $this->CommentDate = $CommentDate;
        $this->CommentLikes = $CommentLikes;
    }
}
```

And my php codes returns an array full of `Comment` objects.Now when i receive this in swift i do something like this

```
  let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [Any]
  print(jsonData[0])
```

Printing this returns me

```
{
    CommentDate = "2017-06-29 01:21:57";
    CommentLikes = 2;
    CommenterName = muradsh;
}
```

And when i want to access one of this objects like this

```
           print(jsonData[0][2])
```

or this

```
 print(jsonData[0]["CommenterName"])
```

it returns me this following error `Type 'Any' has no subscript members`.
How can i get access to `CommenterName` in jsonData?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the data you get is really an array of objects try casting it like this:

```
let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [[String: Any]]
```